# Not installed applications in Android settings/apps

Tags: android, adb, uninstallation

Apps installed by IDE (namely idea) and uninstalled in device now in status "not installed". Android 4.4, Nexus 7 2012.

[image: apps screenshot]

And now i can't install them again with Idea without executing `adb uninstall`. But, for example, i did not remember the package of "simplest" and have no idea where i can get it. No details from `adb shell pm list packages` nor from "App info":

[image]

This behavior began from about 4.3 continues in 4.4.

Play Store apps may be removed as usual.

UPD: Forgot the question. Who is in fault and what to do?

Comment: How did you open that activity from the first screen?

Comment: First screenshot is "Settings/Apps"; second is result of tap on last entry

Comment: Do you have multiple users on that device?

Comment: Ha, yes. For testing purpose. And so what? I have not used that user for month.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for that is that you use multiple accounts on that device. So if the app is installed for one user you can see that another user has this app installed and that the app uses space on your device, while it is not installed for the currient user. That means it is on your device but not installed for your currient user.

The solution is to log in with the second pofile and uninstall the *not installed* apps there too.

Comment: Exactly! ABD installs app for both users. I did not expect that at all. Settings/apps show me app from another user. And i did not expect that to ><

Comment: That's the precise reason. Google should make it more obvious. 'Not installed' is not at all intuitive